# Highlight Row of Checkboxes if NONE are Checked

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

In my spreadsheet, I would like to highlight a series of cells (all in the same row) between two columns when **all** of the boxes are not checked.

For example, in the sheet below, I would like to highlight D4:I4 because none of the boxes are checked.

[image: Screenshot of example]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add formula to conditional formatting:

```
=not(or($D1:$I1))
```

and apply to `D:I` range

[image]